# Efficient size choice for SciPy Discrete Sine Transform

Tags: matlab, scipy

I noticed that SciPy has an implementation of the Discrete Sine Transform, and I was comparing it to the one that's in MATLAB.  The MATLAB documentation notes that for best performance, the size of the inputs should be 2^p -1, presumably for a divide and conquer strategy.  Is this also true for the SciPy implementation?

Comment: A little fooling around, using the default values in scipy.fftpack.dst() indicates that lengths of 2^n are the fastest...

Comment: Is dst using any fast method though, or is an N^2 algorithm?

Comment: Since it is in the fftpack module, it is not surprising that it uses FFT methods which are not N^2. I just used x = np.random.rand(2**n) and then used %timeit to measure how fast scipy.fftpack.dst(x) was. It is roughly N log2(N) as expected up to 2**20...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question is old, I happen to have just ran some tests and then stumbled upon this question.
The answer is ***yes***. Internally, scipy seems to converts the array to size `M = 2*(N+1)`.
Ideally, `M = 2^i`, for some integer i. Therefore, N should follow `N = 2^i - 1`. The following picture shows how timings scale with fft-size. Note that the orange line is much smoother, indicating no unexpected memory overhead.

- Green line: N = 2^i
- Blue line: N = 2^i + 1
- Orange line: N = 2^i - 1

[image: fft-size [N] vs solving times [s]

**UPDATE**
After digging some more into the documentation of scipy.fftpack, I found that the above answer is only partly true. According to the documentation, "SciPy’s FFTPACK has efficient functions for radix {2, 3, 4, 5}". This means that instead of efficiently doing arrays of size `M = 2^i`, it can handle any `M = 2^i * 3^j * 5^k` (4 is not a prime). The optimum for scipy.fftpack.dst (or dct) is then `M - 1`. Finding those numbers can be a little awkward, but luckily there's a [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html) for that, too!

*Please note that the above graph is log-log scale, so speedups of 40 or so are not uncommon. Thus, choosing a fast size can make you calculations orders of magnitudes faster! (I found this out the hard way).*